# Create pages in published code

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I want to know whether we can add new pages in depolyed MVC project code?

Based on my experience, it is  not possible.

Please share your thoughts.

P.S:  I need to add two new pages in published MVC code. So there is no chance to write any additional code in controller and model part.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add `.cshtml` to your publish folder in view, but you cann't add server side code in publish `dll`

Comment: How to do render the new pages from the layout.cshtml. if directly give view name it doesn't work. It throws error ly